# Android Emulator internal storage is almost full

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium, internal-storage

the Android emulator popped a message saying "Internal storage is almost full" when I was running my Appium testing case. I have already set the internal storage to 2G. I checked the storage setting, the available space was 0.00b. The detailed storage screenshot is on https://discuss.appium.io/t/avd-internal-storage-is-full/11060

I was wondering if there is a way to check the storage composition to see which file occupies the 2G internal storage.

Comment: The image in the link is not available.

Answer (score 5):

Its very simple. 
Goto AVD Manager. Then Click an option on Device that you want to clear its storage > Wipe Data

DONE

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the storage on your computer, you can expand the storage capacity of the emulator. Go to the Virtual Device Manager, find your emulator and edit it. Go to the advanced settings -> Memory and Storage and edit `Internal Storage`:

[image]

---

There are also options that don't involve expanding the storage:

The first thing you can try is wiping the emulator's cache. Do that by first running it, going into the settings app, going into storage settings and wiping the cache.

There's the obvious one: delete apps and files on the device you don't need.

Alternatively, you can completely wipe the contents of the emulator. Make sure the emulator isn't running first, then open the Virtual Device Manager. Find the emulator you're using, press the arrow and select "Wipe Data". Note that this deletes everything on the emulator